# When i try to render ejs file in my express application showing Cannot find module 'ejs'

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const morgan = require("morgan");

const app = express();

app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(express.json());

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("./view/create.ejs");
});

mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/Pull_request")
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(8000, () => {
      console.log("app is listening on port 8000");
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

I'm trying to use ejs in a express app but I keep gettin the "Error: Cannot find module 'ejs '" error as I try to load the localhost.

I've already:

Installed ejs in the project folder, tried to install it globally and in the parent folder of the project.
Added to the package.json file both express and ejs ( installed with the --save option)

Ejs seems to be there but does not work.

Comment: Go back to basics: get rid of morgan and mongoose, get rid of the json handler, etc, and just set up a new project that builds a plain express app, with the latest version of express, the `ejs` engine registered, and renders `index.html` (your template files don't need an `.ejs` extension. In fact, that just makes it harder to work with your templates. Use their normal extension) on the `/` route. In part for you, but also in part because if _that_ doesn't work, now you have code you can show in your post that others can replicate, which they can't do if your code needs a database just to run

Comment: Can I see your package.json where ejs is there and package-lock.json where ejs is too. And node_modules folder included ejs . Check around it first